# thesis formatting

Tags: formatting

I have a thesis template using the `fancyhdr` package in which the chapters and titles are written bold and have large margins. Since I am doing my thesis, my school formatting requires center page titles and 1in from the top, I tried to adjust the `.cls` file but I couldn't get it, please help me finding any other way to write as the sample image shown below,

[image]

[image]

This is part of the `.cls`:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2.0ex plus0.5ex minus0.2ex}
%\usepackage{vmargin}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGINS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\setmarginsrb  { 1.0in}  % left margin
    %                    { 1.0in}  % top margin
%                        { 1.0in}  % right margin
%                        { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
%                       {  0pt}  % head height
%                        {0.25in}  % head sep
%                        {   0pt}  % foot height
%                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\footskip 0.5in %not fully tested, but I think this is the thing to modify.
%\raggedbottom
\setlength{\topskip}{1\topskip \@plus 5\p@}
\doublehyphendemerits=10000       % No consecutive line hyphens.
%\brokenpenalty=10000              % No broken words across columns/pages.
%\widowpenalty=9999                % Almost no widows at bottom of page.
%\clubpenalty=9999                 % Almost no orphans at top of page.
%\interfootnotelinepenalty=9999    % Almost never break footnotes.
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\lhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\sl{\rightmark}}}
%\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl{\leftmark}}]{\rm\thepage}
%\chead{}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}\cfoot{}
%\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\btypeout{\thechapter\space #1}\markboth{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}
%\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
%\hbox{}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\newpage
%\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
```

Comment: If you need to do this yourself, I would recommend using one of the self-contained document classes like `memoir` or `scrbook`. These classes are well documented and allow you to change everything fairly easily.  You shouldn't be changing a class file yourself, generally, especially as a new LaTeX user.